# wrapping long equation using square stretched bracket

Tags: equations, split

How do we split long equation in which a command `\left[` and `\right]` is used? My equation is as follow

```
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
z &=-2Re\left[B^\ast\left(\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{N}\alpha_k\zeta^{1-k}\left(1-is_1\right)+\alpha_k\frac{1}{\zeta^{1-k}}\left(1+is_1\right)+\beta_k\zeta^{1-k}\left(i+s_1\right)+\beta_k\frac{1}{\zeta^{1-k}}\left(s_1-i\right)\right)\\
&+\left(B^{\prime\ast}+iC^{\prime\ast}\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{N}\alpha_k\zeta^{1-k}\left(1-is_2\right)+\alpha_k\frac{1}{\zeta^{1-k}}\left(1+is_2\right)+\beta_k\zeta^{1-k}\left(i+s_2\right)+\beta_k\frac{1}{\zeta^{1-k}}\left(s_2-i\right)\right)\right]
\end{split}
\end{align}
```

LaTeX complains because the `\left[` and `\right]` command are now separated by the `\\`. I am also using `split` command, unlike other identical post.

I am using `\usepackage{amsmath}`

I use `\left[` and `\right]` because I must stretch the bracket; unless there is another way to do it. Could anyone help me, please?

Comment: you can use `\bigl( ..\\ \bigr)`

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Is there any reason why you have a `split` environment nested in an `align`?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks. It is not working as expected. The bracket is not stretched.

Comment: @Bernard because I still have another equation in the same line. The one I showed above is just an example.

Comment: `\bigr` is a fixed size use `\Biggr` or whatever size you need.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It works well now! thanks! solved.

Answer (score 0):

Answer provided by @David Carlisle is as follow.

\bigr is a fixed size use \Biggr or whatever size you need. – David Carlisle 2 mins ago